# VBA, formatting/unknown issue causing vba to not work

Tags: excel, vba

1) My vba copies and pastes columns from sheet a to sheet b (a table) .

2) My next vba code is ran ontop of this table and I get an error.

However if I copy and paste the problem header and data manually from sheet A to Sheet B my macro(2) will work.

Also I should mention this particular column causing the problem is a column with dates. But I have tried both formats, general and date, ive tried using a formula (=SheetA!BU1:) and pasted down into sheet 2, and I've tried a macro to copy and paste the one column.. nothing works!

Not sure if it is my code, table, format, etc.

Here is my copy and paste macro, the type mismatch does not occur here but in my other code that is not included.

```
Sub importtodatabase(from_ws, to_ws)
    Dim rng As Range, trgtCell As Range
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trgt As Worksheet
    Set src = Worksheets(from_ws)
    Set trgt = Worksheets(to_ws)
    Dim row_num As Integer
    Dim Max_row_data As Integer
    Dim source_tab As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets(to_ws).Select
    Max_row_data = get_max_row("")

    If Max_row_data <> 2 Then
        Max_row_data = Max_row_data + 1
    End If

    Sheets("Mappings").Select
    max_row = get_max_row("")


    With src
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Rows(1), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            For row_num = 2 To max_row
                If from_ws = Range("BU" & row_num).value Then
                    If rng = Range("BV" & row_num).value Then
                        rng = Range("BW" & row_num).value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next row_num

            Set trgtCell = trgt.Rows(1).Find(rng.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

            'If .Range(rng.Offset(1), .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

                If Not trgtCell Is Nothing Then
                    .Range(rng.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.count, rng.Column).End(xlUp)).copy
                    With trgt
                        .Cells(Max_row_data, trgtCell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End With
                End If
            'End If
        Next rng
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this question different from the prior one that looked very similar? Where does the type mismatch occur? You also have left screen-updating off and not included the function which you call.

Comment: @QHarr , yes xD . I guess I could update that one.

Comment: Where does the type mismatch occur? Where can we find sample data? These are essential in order to solve the problem. Next time include those right away please.

Comment: @Luuklag , type mismatch doesnt occur in this code. Just thought someone may have experience with a problem column.

Comment: Then please edit your question to avoid the confusion.